# Convert groups of rows from column format in groups of columns in rows format

Tags: excel, rows, transpose, vba

I am trying to write a macro in VBA to transpose columns to rows in this style:

it is:

```
A
B
C

D
E
F
```

should be:

```
A   D
B   E
C   F
```

Has someone any idea?

Comment: We'll need a lot more information.  Is it every three rows, need to be copied over? Every group until a blank? What have you tried so far? Please post what methods you've attempted, along with any code.  Also, it would help to read over [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The number of the values of each group that has to be "transfered" is 13. I have 65 groups. Until now I have tried with excel commands (index, etc) but it is not working properly. I have tried to edit already uploaded vba scripts put they most of them are simple columns to rows and not in this style.

Comment: In fact this is am more "copy" function than "transpose" or "convert".

Comment: So, you need every 13 rows, from column A, to be copied to column B, then the next 13 to C, ...etc etc?

Comment: @BruceWayne, exactly... I have tried to make it with a makro and then change it to make loops, but I am not fit in vba.

Comment: Something like that:                                                                                Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Range("A1:B11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow&, groupSize&, i&, k&
Dim rng As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

groupSize = 13
k = 2 ' start the pasting in the second column

For i = 14 To lastRow
    Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + groupSize - 1, 1))
    rng.Cut Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(13, k))
    i = i + 12
    k = k + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of the correct answer of BruceWayne:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow&, groupSize&, i&, k&
Dim rng As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

groupSize = 13
k = 1 ' start the pasting in the first column
j = 1

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + groupSize - 1, 1))
    rng.Cut Range(Cells(j, k), Cells(j + 12, k))
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 12
    If k = 14 Then
    k = 1
    j = j + 13
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The only difference is that now the data are written not in a single row but in a group of rows. All credits to BruceWayne.